# Convert columns of words and weight into sparse matrix

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have a table like below:

```
DocumentId Words Weight

1   alpha   2.5
1   beta    4.7
1   gamma   3
2   beta    8
2   gamma   2
3   alpha   5
4   apha    2
4   gamma   6
```

I want it to convert it to

```
DocumentId  alpha   beta   gamma
       1       2.5  4.7    3
       2       0    8      2
       3       5    0      0
       4       2    0      6
```

The issue is I have around 60,000 thousands unique words and 7 millions documents.

Is there a efficient way to convert this?

Comment: Please add the text representation of the dataframe. Something that can be copied into a text editor

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried pivoting using pivot function from pandas but it fails miserably

Answer (score 0):

Just had to do this myself. The proper terminology is converting from a longitudinal format to a wide format. You'll want to use [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). Based off the columns you want to reduce and the new column headers you want, your code will be

```
df.pivot(index = 'DocumentId', columns = 'Words')
df.fillna(0)
```